# firebase deployment issue getting a page from firebase telling me firebase hosting setup is complete when i should get my website. react app

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-hosting

I have build a react app using firebase and firestore to create a to do list and I try to deploy my app and I get a page from firebase telling me welcome to firebase hosting setup complete instead of my website. everything was working fine before I deployed my site with firebase hosting now all I get is this welcome page from firebase. How do I get my site on line after I already deployed it?

Answer (score 2):

you can either use Github actions for automatically deployed on branch push

if you have not set up GitHub action then you can easily deploy using this command

```
yarn run build

firebase deploy
```

Answer (score 1):

use these commands once more
yarn build or npm run build

firebase deploy

i think you have missed build before last command firebase deploy

Comment: i got the same issue then build it again and then used firebase deploy